# Passing variable into request nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, request

i have a little proble here, I want to make a request to PHP server from my node server. i already done like this

```
request('http://services.qlue.id/external/crop_generate_data.php', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response);
        result += response;
    });
```

But i just want to throw this response to new response similar like this

```
var result = '';
    request('http://foo.bar.com', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    res.send(200, result);
```

But what i get is only empty result. I expect new JSON response inside it. Can i have a little help?

Comment: Are you recieving any error? Write if(error) console.log(error)

Comment: I don't receive any error, instead i have body response from the URL but i cannot passing it to result variable and show it as new json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.. I made node http module inplace of 'request' module

```
    let chunkData = '';
    let request = http.get('http://services.qlue.id/external/crop_generate_data.php', function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunkData += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            res.send(chunkData)
        })
    });
    request.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
    request.end();
```